# Exchange 2013 Add SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, exchange-server

I am trying to add an SSL certificate to my exchange server, but I cannot figure out what I should be putting for the location where it saves the certificate request.  I have put in a path to a local NAS server, but I am getting the following error:

[image: Error]

Here is the path that I am using:

[image: Path]

What is it looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common reason:
Check that the share behind your UNC path allows write/change access for the "Exchange Trusted Subsystem".

Comment: What does that mean exactly?  I set the folder permissions on that specific folder to have public read/write access for the purposes of this -

Comment: I created a folder and add that permission and it worked!  Thank you!